# How to replace apt() with Gradle 3.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I upgrade the gradle file to 3.0 facing issues in android annotations process.

```
implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.3.2"
        annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.3.2"
```

I have replaced all existing annotation kinds of stuff

```
// apply plugin: 'android-apt'
// classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

but am not sure how can I replace the below lines

```
    apt {
        arguments {
            androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
            resourcePackageName "$appId"
        }
    }
```

without above line the AndroidManifest file not included while run tine, also added this in defalutConfig

```
  javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
                }
        }
```

any help much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
   javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ['resourcePackageName': android.defaultConfig.applicationId]
            }
   }
```

More [info here](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/CustomizeAnnotationProcessing).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gabriele, unfortunately i can able to run it show error on all activities for eg "activity.SplashActivity_"